# A good way to corrupt TCP connection

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm writing a async c++ TCP network client/server using boost::asio, and I need for both to be rock solid under any circumstances of usage. My main concern are faulty connections, which have caused me a lot of hard to find problems in the past.

When writing the app, the connectivity is usually good or very good. What I need is to find a good way to simulate all kinds of bad connections with packet loss, corruption, latency spikes and other problems.

Are there any drivers or software which would let me do that?

Comment: Mac OS X has a prefpane that allows you to set network latency, speed and packet loss. The same applies to iOS. Don't know about other platforms. More can be found here: http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/

Comment: This is a useless endeavour. TCP performs a checksum that detects accidential (though not _malicious_) corruption. Also, it transparently deals with packet loss and increased latency without you having much of a means of influencing it. Insofar, it is pretty useless to simulate that kind of stuff.

Comment: Better simulate receiving of only 1 byte per recv-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several commercial products to do this, some good some bad. They are, obviously, very platform specific and you do not say anything about your platform of choice. The kind of issues you point at are OS level, boost/C++ has nothing to do with such.

As for corruption, you really can't have any claim unless you cryptographically sign the traffic.

Comment: The app should work on both linux and windows. Can you name the solutions you have in mind?

Comment: [netlimiter](http://netlimiter.com/), [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/)

Answer (score 2):

TCP is fairly robust. It already takes care of packet loss, corruption (for random bit flips, not attacks) and throttling for you. The only thing you app needs to be able to handle are latency spikes and connection dropping.

You can get fairly good mileage by introducing random delay in you read methods or by killing the connection at random points in time.

However, the best way of dealing with it is to think of the worst scenarios for you app and just test a few of those.